# For quadratic polynomial $p(x)$, if $p(x)=x$ has no real roots, then $p(p(x))=x$ also has no real roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Let $p(x)$ be a quadratic polynomial so that $p(x)=x$ has no real roots. Prove that $p(p(x)) = x$ will also have no real roots.

My solution:

$p(x) - x = 0$ has no roots

So $p(x) > x$ or $p(x) < x$ for all $x$.

Let $p(x) > x$

So, $p(p(x)) - p(x) =0$ has no roots or

$p(p(x))> p(x) > x$

So even $p(p(x)) - x$ has no real roots.

Similarly it can be proved for $p(x) < x$ for all $x$.

My Doubt:

> Can we just substitute $p(x)$ into $p(x) > x$ as $p(x)$ has a real range for real $x$?

Is there another intuitive solution?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: $p(x) > x \implies p(p(x)) > p(x)$ would need you to show $p$ is increasing first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose by contradiction that $p(p(x))=x$ has a real root $a$, i.e., $p(p(a))=a$. Note that $p(a)=b\neq a$ since $p(x)=x$ has no real roots. WLOG, assume $b>a$. Then
$$\begin{cases}
p(a)=b,\\
p(b)=a.
\end{cases}\label{eq1} \tag{$\star$}$$
Let $f(x)= p(x)-x$ for all $x$. It follows eq. \eqref{eq1} that
$$\begin{cases}
f(a)=b-a>0,\\
f(b)=a-b<0.
\end{cases}$$
Since $p$ is a quadratic polynomial, $f$ is continuous, thus there must exist some $x_0\in (a,b)$ such that $f(x_0)= 0$, i.e., $p(x_0)=x_0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the solution . But is my solution also right? Or any corrections needed?

Comment: @RishiShekher  I think you are right. In your proof, you obtain that: either $p(x)>x$, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ or $p(x)<x$, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. That is similar to what I did in my proof, since $p(x)-x$ is continuous. If you didn't use the fact that $p(x)-x$ is continuous, then you can only deduce that: for a fixed $x\in \mathbb{R}$, either $p(x)<x$ or $p(x)>x$, which is weaker than what we previously concluded.